# How do I fix the conditional dropdown issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a conditional dropdown in which by default the values are "Select vehicle make" and "Select vehicle model". The select vehicle model is disabled by default because I want the customer to choose the make first so that we can load related models.

There's another option called "other". What it means is if the make and model are not listed in the list choose other. The other will bring two input text field where the customer can write make and model by themselves.

Issue 1: Now coming to the issue, if I select any "Make", by default the "Model" field should just become active, and that's working fine, but what's wrong with it is the model dropdown is selecting "- other -" by default instead of "Select vehicle model".

Issue 2: How do I replace the model dropdown with an input text field when I choose "- other -" from the "Model" dropdown.

Looking forward to a solution.

```js
var $make = $('#make'),
  $model = $('#model'),
  $options = $model.find('option');

$('#make').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value == '*') {
    removeClassDynamicClass();
    changeModelDiv();
    $("#others").addClass("hide");
    $("#others input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(".model-div-not-others").removeClass("hide");
    $(".model-div-not-others select").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".model-div-for-others").addClass("hide");
    $('#model').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#country-registeration").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#opt-details").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (this.value == 'others') {

    if ($('.dynamic-class-4').hasClass('col-lg-4')) {
      $('.dynamic-class-4').removeClass('col-lg-4');
      $('.dynamic-class-4').addClass('col-lg-3');
    }
    changeModelDiv();
    $("#others").removeClass("hide");
    $("#others input").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".model-div-not-others").addClass("hide");
    $(".model-div-for-others").removeClass("hide");
    $(".model-div-for-others input").removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#model').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#opt-details").removeAttr('disabled');
    // In-case of other countries added remove the below commented code
    //$("#country-registeration").removeAttr('disabled');

  } else {
    $model.html($options.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
    removeClassDynamicClass();
    changeModelDiv();
    $("#others").addClass("hide");
    $("#others input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(".model-div-not-others").removeClass("hide");
    $(".model-div-not-others select").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".model-div-for-others").addClass("hide");
    $('#model').removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#opt-details").removeAttr('disabled');
    // In-case of other countries added remove the below commented code
    //$("#country-registeration").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});

function removeClassDynamicClass() {
  if ($('.dynamic-class-4').hasClass('col-lg-3')) {
    $('.dynamic-class-4').removeClass('col-lg-3');
    $('.dynamic-class-4').addClass('col-lg-4');
  }
}

function changeModelDiv() {
  if ($('#make').val() == 'others') {
    $('.model-div-not-others').addClass("hide");
    $('.model-div-for-others').removeClass("hide");
    $('#model-others').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#model').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    if ($('.model-div-not-others').hasClass("hide")) {
      $('.model-div-not-others').removeClass("hide");
      $('.model-div-for-others').addClass("hide");
      $('#model').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('#model-others').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
}

$('#make').trigger('change');
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 dynamic-class-4 float-left mb-3">
  <label class="car-list-step-label">Make</label>
  <select class="form-control custom-select" name="make" id="make">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="*">Select vehicle make</option>
    <option value="1">Acura</option>
    <option value="2">Abarth</option>
    <option value="3">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option value="4">Alpina</option>
    <option value="5">Aston Martin</option>
    <option value="others">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- Make Others Details -->
<div id="others" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 dynamic-class-4 float-left mb-3 hide">
  <label class="car-list-step-label">Make (others)</label>
  <input id="details" name="details" type="text" placeholder="Make" class="form-control car-list-input">
</div>

<!-- Vehicle Model -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 dynamic-class-4 float-left mb-3">
  <div class="model-div-not-others">
    <label class="car-list-step-label">Model</label>
    <select class="form-control custom-select" name="model" id="model">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select vehicle model</option>
      <!-- Acura -->
      <option value="1">1.6 EL</option>
      <option value="1">1.7 EL</option>
      <option value="1">2.3 CL</option>
      <option value="1">2.5 TL</option>
      <option value="1">3.0 CL</option>
      <option value="1">3.2 TL</option>
      <option value="1">3.5 RL</option>
      <option value="1">CL</option>
      <option value="1">CSX</option>
      <option value="1">EL</option>
      <option value="1">ILX</option>
      <option value="1">Integra</option>
      <option value="1">Legend</option>
      <option value="1">MDX</option>
      <option value="1">NSX</option>
      <option value="1">NSX-T</option>
      <option value="1">RDX</option>
      <option value="1">RL</option>
      <option value="1">RSX</option>
      <option value="1">SLX</option>
      <option value="1">TL</option>
      <option value="1">TSX</option>
      <option value="1">Vigor</option>
      <option value="1">ZDX</option>
      <option value="1">- Other -</option>
      <!-- Abarth -->
      <option value="2">124</option>
      <option value="2">500</option>
      <option value="2">500C</option>
      <option value="2">595</option>
      <option value="2">595C</option>
      <option value="2">695</option>
      <option value="2">Grande Punto</option>
      <option value="2">Punto Evo</option>
      <option value="2">Spider Cabrio</option>
      <option value="2">- Other -</option>
      <!-- Alfa Romeo -->
      <option value="3">145</option>
      <option value="3">146</option>
      <option value="3">147</option>
      <option value="3">155</option>
      <option value="3">156</option>
      <option value="3">159</option>
      <option value="3">164</option>
      <option value="3">166</option>
      <option value="3">33</option>
      <option value="3">4C</option>
      <option value="3">75</option>
      <option value="3">Alfetta</option>
      <option value="3">GT</option>
      <option value="3">GTV</option>
      <option value="3">GTV-6</option>
      <option value="3">GTV6</option>
      <option value="3">Giulia</option>
      <option value="3">Guiletta</option>
      <option value="3">Milano</option>
      <option value="3">Mito</option>
      <option value="3">Spider</option>
      <option value="3">- Other -</option>
      <!-- Alpina -->
      <option value="4">B4</option>
      <option value="4">B5</option>
      <option value="4">- Other -</option>
      <!-- Aston Martin -->
      <option value="5">Cygnet</option>
      <option value="5">DB7</option>
      <option value="5">DB9</option>
      <option value="5">Rapide S</option>
      <option value="5">Vanquish S</option>
      <option value="5">Vantage</option>
      <option value="5">- Other -</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- Vehicle Model Others -->
  <div class="model-div-for-others hide">
    <label class="car-list-step-label">Model (others)</label>
    <input disabled id="model-others" name="models" type="text" placeholder="Model" class="form-control car-list-input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All of the 2nd `select`'s options have the same value.  How will you know which one has been picked?  Change `<option value=` to `<option data-make=` and match on `[data-make=`.   2. Don't "replace" the `select` - hide it and show previously hidden inputs `$(".model-div-for-others").show()`

Comment: For issue #1, the "Select vehicle model" is no longer an option once the <select> values change.  You'll need to retain that first option when it populates the #model options. Perhaps the logic should be to (1) remove disabled from the first option and set it as the selected option, then (2) update the value of the "Select vehicle model" option to match the value of the selected model, then (3) update the #make select list
`$('#model').removeAttr('disabled');
$("#model option:eq(0)").removeAttr("disabled");
$("#model option:eq(0)").val("3");
$("#model option:eq(0)").prop("selected",true);`

Comment: For issue #2, you can hide the parent div containing the <select>, then show the parent div containing the others text input field.`$(".model-div-not-others").hide();
$(".model-div-for-others").show();`

Comment: @CherylVelez I tried. Couldn't succeed. Any previews, please?

Comment: @BillNathan I posted a solution with a link to CodePen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix issue #1, one option is to pre-assign a value to the "-Select Vehicle Model" option before running the filter, then set it as the "selected" option.

```
// pre-assign a value to the first option - "Select Vehicle Model" 
$("#model option:eq(0)").val(this.value);

// run the filter, which will now include the first option
$model.html($options.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));

// make the first option the selected option
$("#model option:eq(0)").prop("selected",true);
```

My solution on CodePen: https://codepen.io/onegrumpybunny/full/NmjzXb

For issue #2, you can hide the div containing the "model" select and show the div containing the "other" text field.

```
$('#model').on('change', function() {
   if ($('#model :selected').text() == '- Other -') {

     // uncomment this to hide the "model" select when "other" option is selected
     //$('.model-div-not-others').addClass("hide"); 

     $('.model-div-for-others').removeClass("hide");
     $('#model-others').removeAttr("disabled");
   } else {
     $('.model-div-for-others').addClass("hide");
     $('#model-others').attr("disabled","disabled");
   }
});
```

A word of warning though, using the text of an option is not best practice.  I'd recommend assigning a valid value to each option. Then, add a data-attribute value for each option and filter on that instead (I believe someone else mentioned this as well).  This will leave you with valid values coming from your form.

--- edit ---
Here is an example of your app with valid values assigned to each option and filtering done on a data attribute value: https://codepen.io/onegrumpybunny/full/wZevjy

Comment: Inside the model drop down, if you notice there's another option called "- other -" this other means that if the model is not available we will switch the dropdown into an input text field and you can write the model by your hand. Just like under "make" there's the other option. That means if you can't find a make in the list add make and model manually using the input field.

Comment: @BillNathan Ah, gotcha. I've updated my answer and the CodePen accordingly.

Comment: @BillNathan I added a link to an alternate example that uses the option's data attribute in the filter instead of the option's value. This may yield more useful results from your form.

Comment: If you notice here, when I selected the - Other - option from models dropdown. You switched the model dropdown to input text field. Now there is no option I can come back to the previous models except refresh. So I would like the - other - input field to be added next to model dropdown not by replacing it.

Comment: @BillNathan This is what you requested in your question. You can offer a link, that when clicked, it will hide the active div and unhide the hidden one.

Comment: Last example, please? :$

Comment: @BillNathan To keep the "model" select visible, just comment out this line: `$('.model-div-not-others').addClass("hide");`  in the "model" on change event. The codepen has been updated accordingly.  Any additional show/hide actions you want to add as selections are made can be done by adding or commenting similar lines in your code.

Comment: This I did achieve. But the issue was if you switch to -Other- to anything else in the list, the model doesn't hide back, and that's why I needed an example. How do I hide it back if I select anything else except -Other-? Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @BillNathan I've added to the code snippet in my answer. The "Model (others)" box is hidden if the model select changes to something besides "- Other -".